# Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS installer can't detect my pre-installed windows7 on asus S46C

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my asus S46C with dual boot, but I can't see my Windows partitions when trying to install. Only the whole disk is available when I choose `something else` option and ther is no `install alongside option`.

Comment: This is very unclear but I think you are saying, after installing Ubuntu I can't boot to windows anymore ?

Comment: No. Windows7 has no problem. When I reach to Ubuntu partation step, I can see my HDD as all free space only. Can't see my installed windoes7 partitions.

Comment: Ubuntu offer to install the whole disk. I know my english isn't too good. Sorry for that.

Comment: Did this computer come with Windows 8 pre installed ?, I think it did, if so run this command `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` and add the results of the section `Partition table scan:` here

Comment: Number   Start(sector)    End(sector)   Size     Code     Name      are apper as empty list.

Comment: No the top part, the four lines under `Partition table scan:`

Comment: MBR: MBR only, BSD: not present, APM: not present, GPT: present

Comment: OK, related http://superuser.com/questions/744916/ubuntu-14-04-installer-doesnt-show-existing-partitions I will write you a better answer though as this has value here.

Comment: So thank for your help. I'm begineer of linux user. I have no experiences and so trying to learn more. :)

Comment: I typed Sudo fixparts /dev/sda and it ask Y/N. What should I do? If I type yes, Can I data lost on my windows 7. Help me please.

Comment: What did it ask ? It should not affect your Windows partition, only edits the MBR on your drive Here is the manual for fixparts http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/fixparts.8.html What is a MBR https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DualBoot/Mbr, I can't guarantee you anything, I can't just recreate the issue to test it, the superuser link says it worked and it seems unlikely but it is your decision.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here, indicated by running `sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda` is multiple partition tables left over from a pre-install of Windows 8 (probably for 8.1 and 10 too).

You can use the program `fixparts` from a live medium, it is pre-installed.

Choose `try Ubuntu` and open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run

```
fixparts /dev/sda
```

The program will detect the problem automatically and propose solution. [More details here](http://www.rodsbooks.com/fixparts/) if you're interested.

[Superuser source](https://superuser.com/questions/744916/ubuntu-14-04-installer-doesnt-show-existing-partitions)

Comment: I got this message "Problem opening /dev/sda for reading! Error is 13. You must run this program as root or use sudo!    Unable to read MBR data from '/dev/sda'! Exiting!" When I used with sudo, it ask yes  or No. What should I do? Can I lost my Windows7 and data.

Comment: But what is the question it asks yes or no to ?

Comment: The GPT signatures are probably left over from a previous partition table. Do you want to delete them (if you answer 'Y', this will happen immediately)?

Comment: That in no way indicates it will format your drive or remove any of your data, only remove the GPT from the MBR, I gave you all the information I have so you can make a decision, I would say it will be fine, but no guarantees, I don't have experience with fix parts

Comment: OK, I should try it later. I don't finish my assignment and so I can't lost. I will try it later. Thank